# Bandwidth question if file returns no source code

Tags: php, bandwidth

I was wondering how much  (or would it waste any) bandwidth if you request a page at regular intervals?

If i used ajax to get a page every 10 seconds and the page returns no sourcecode whats so ever and its literaly empty, does this waste any bandwidth ?

Comment: I asked my hosting provider they used a fancy word for saying it would but it would be so insignificant. I think it depended on headers how much headers you send. also if the file was did not change browsers usually cache it, and simply load what was previously sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll still take up a "slot" on your web server for a minimal amount of time, and the HTTP request and response headers still need to be transferred between the client and the server, so yes it'll still take up a (minimal) amount of bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought so. A few bytes if any, but you are still calling a file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have the bytes comprising the request and the acknowledgement from the server.

Presumably the web server would be returning a http status code of 200 (OK) or 204 (No response) so you'll have the header data for that.